# How to use filters on Foreignkey Fields in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

In the below class 'dep' is a Foreign Key field associated with Employee model.

Views.py

```
class Sample(ListAPIView)
queryset=Employee.Objects.all()
serializer_class = EmployeeSerializer
filter_backends = [SearchFilter]
search_fields = ['dep']
```

Models.py

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    FirstName=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    LastName = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    Salary = models.FloatField()
    Email = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    Dep   =models.Foreignkey(Department)
```

but when I pass dep has a filter to the endpt , it throws Related Field got invalid lookup: icontains Error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform a related lookup on a ForeignKey or ManyToManyField with the lookup API double-underscore notation `__`

try this

```
search_fields = ['DEP__id', 'DEP__field_name']
```

Refer this https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/

Comment: I am passing Department name in the filter , so its  [DEP__name] column name or     [DEPARTMENT__name]  model name

Comment: DEP__name this one